# Почему ИИ пишут на питоне, если он медленный?

Tags: python, искусственный-интеллект

Зачем это делают? Питон это довольно медленный язык

Comment: ИИ обучается и выполняется не на питоне, это просто удобное высокоуровневое АПИ, а внутри там обычный C/C++ и код для видеокарт

Comment: Библиотеки машинного обучения используют Си, Фортран даже, и Си++. Обертка в виде Питона позволяет обеспечить удобство работы.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.zfort.com.ua/blog/luchshii-yazyk-dlya-programmirovaniya-ii-rukovodstvo-polzovatelya - тут приведет топ основных языков, на которых пишут ИИ.

---

По поводу питона сказано:

> Прежде всего, Python - язык с открытым исходным кодом. Это означает, что он доступен для любых модификаций, которые разработчики сочтут нужными. Этот язык программирования постоянно развивается, что упрощает его синтаксис и повышает его эффективность. Во-вторых, существует большое количество готовых к использованию библиотек, которые помогают ускорить написание кода. Например, TensorFlow широко применяется для машинного обучения и работы с наборами данных; scikit - для обучения моделей машинного обучения; PyTorch - для обработки речи и для компьютерного зрения. Это ощутимое преимущество, которое может помочь ускорить разработку и сэкономить ресурсы, поскольку позволяет применять готовые решения вместо их создания с нуля.